# Spring security doesn't work when unwanted basic authentication header found

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jboss

Below issue occurred only in https environment.

Jboss Web server authenticated with basic authentication. 
Now when accessing application inside deployed on jboss, all request contains Basic authorization headers. Now when using correct credentials , i could not able to login. If am using my application directly without going to jboss basic authentication , then i am able to login in the application and everything working fine. Issue in spring security if unwanted basic authentication. I tried with disabling basic authentication but not work.

Below are my code. SecurityContext

```
package com.adv.admin.context;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import com.adv.admin.util.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.adv.admin.util.CustomAuthenticationProvider;
import com.adv.admin.util.CustomLogoutSuccessHandler;
import com.coa.idm.annotation.SSOProvider;
import com.coa.idm.filter.SSOProviderType;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@SSOProvider(providerType = SSOProviderType.NONE)
public class LocalSecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    CustomLogoutSuccessHandler customLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/login/**","/logout/**","/views/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/technical_setup/**","/preferences_config/**","/admin_management/**")
                .access("hasRole('SYSADMIN')")
          .antMatchers("/home/**","/custom_help/**","/custom_message/**",
                 "/custom_help_detail/**","/custom_message_detail/**","/admin_property/**")
                .access("hasAnyRole('SYSADMIN','ADMIN')")
          .and()
          .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")
          .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
          .defaultSuccessUrl("/home", true)
          .failureUrl("/login?error=3")
          .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
          .and()
          .logout()
          .logoutUrl("/logout")
          .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
          .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
          .and()
          .sessionManagement()
          .sessionAuthenticationErrorUrl("/login/invalid-session");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**").and().ignoring().antMatchers("/WebHelp/**");
    }
}
```

AuthenticationProvider

```
package com.adv.admin.util;

import java.util.Collection;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.DisabledException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.adv.admin.entity.UserMaster;
import com.adv.admin.model.CustomUser;
import com.adv.admin.repository.AdminRepository;
import com.adv.admin.repository.UserMasterRepository;
import com.adv.admin.services.CustomUserService;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

  @Autowired
  private CustomUserService userService;
  @Autowired
  private AdminRepository adminRepository;
  @Inject
  private UserMasterRepository userMasterRepository;

  @Override
  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();
    UserMaster userMaster;

    if (userService.getdataSourceDilact() != null
            && userService.getdataSourceDilact().equals(Constants.POSTGRES_SQL_Dialect)) {
        userMaster = userMasterRepository.findByUsr(username);
    } else {
        userMaster = userMasterRepository.findByUsr(rightPad(username));
    }

    if (ObjectUtils.isNotEmpty(userMaster)) {
      if (userMaster.getDsbld().equals(Constants.FLAG_Y)) {
        throw new DisabledException(Constants.DISABLED_MESSAGE);
      } else {
        String encryptedPassword = (password + "        ").substring(0, 8);
        encryptedPassword = new String(LogonSecurity.encrypt(encryptedPassword.toCharArray()));
        if (!encryptedPassword.equals(userMaster.getPswd())) {
          throw new BadCredentialsException(Constants.WRONG_CREDENTIALS_MESSAGE);
        } else {
          CustomUser user = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);
          Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();
          return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);
        }
      }
    } else {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(Constants.WRONG_CREDENTIALS_MESSAGE);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
    return true;
  }

  private String rightPad(String s) {
    return String.format("%-8s", s);
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What response do you get (with message)? I suspect the jboss setting up the same cookie name, which spring is expecting

Comment: Getting 302 as redirection.